# Transformando algoritimo para o visualg

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Estou começando a estudar algoritmos, e para facilitar tento levar todos os algoritmos para o visualg.

Eu estou com um algoritmo de exemplo mas não estou conseguindo transformar para o visualg alguém pode ajudar?

Sei que "tamanho(frase)" eu mudo para Compr(frase) que vai me dar o numero de caracteres da frase. O problema é que não consigo chamar essa função.

Algoritmo:

```
função inverte(entradas: frase)
início
    resultado <- frase
    para i <- 1 até tamanho(frase)/2 faça
        aux <- frase[i]
        resultado[i] <- frase[tamanho(frase)-i+1]
        resultado[tamanho(frase)-i+1] <- aux
    próximo i
fim  

O que fiz até agora foi:

algoritmo "Teste"

var
    F: caracter

Funcao inverte(): caracter
var

    frase: vetor [1..20] de caracter
    i, j: inteiro

inicio

     Para i de 1 ate Compr(F) faca
       frase[i] <- Copia(F; i, 1)
      FimPara
      j <- Compr(F)
      Para i de 1 ate Compr(F) faca
         Escreva (frase[j])
         j <- j - 1
      FimPara
FimFuncao
inicio

     Escreva ("entre como a palavra: ")
     Leia (F)
     inverter(F)


fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Minha mente não está fresca para Visualg.
Dando uma pesquisada no loop de repetição `PARA` , parece que você esqueceu da instrução de intrementação depois de chamar a função Compr(F).
[Comandos de Repetição](http://www.apoioinformatica.inf.br/produtos/item/14-comandos-de-repeticao)

Answer (score 1):

Depois de bater muito consegui resolver. O problema é que a função precisa de uma variável de retorno e eu não estava fazendo isso.